# How do I disable future dates when using jQuery datepicker inside Tabulator?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, tabulator

I am attempting to disable future dates on a `jQuery datepicker` being utilized with `Tabulator` but to no avail.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#MyDiv", {
    height: "100%",
    layout: "fitDataFill",
    columns: [
        { title: "Date Worked", field: "DateComp", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "date", editor: dateEditor },
        { title: "Memo", field: "Memo", width: 144, hozAlign: "left", editor: "input" },
    ]
});

var dateEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel) {
    var cellValue = moment(cell.getValue(), "MM/DD/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "date");
    input.style.padding = "4px";
    input.style.width = "100%";
    input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    input.value = cellValue;

    onRendered(function () {
        input.style.height = "100%";
        //$(input).datepicker({ endDate: new Date() });
        $(input).datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });
        input.focus();
    });

    function onChange() {
        if (input.value != cellValue) {
            success(moment(input.value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
        } else {
            cancel();
        }
    };
    //submit new value on blur or change
    input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);
    //submit new value on enter
    input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            onChange();
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            cancel();
        }
    });
    return input;
};
```

I have attempted a couple of fixes by tweaking the `datepicker` options list (e.g. `maxDate` and `endDate`) but nothing seems to work.  The future dates on the `datepicker` are selectable regardless.  Is this a `Tabulator` issue?  Or, a `jQuery` issue?

I have found similar questions regarding use of the `jQuery datepicker` on other forums and the recommended solutions always seem to revolve around use of the `maxDate` and `endDate` options.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there are two things that need to be prevented. Being able to click the future date in the date picker, but also Tabulator allowing a date in the cell that is in the future. Which of these are you trying to prevent? Both?

Comment: Good point.  I had only considered disabling future dates in the datepicker but I will also need to prevent entering a future date manually.  I have quickly browsed the moment.js documentation but don't see anything relative to restricting future dates.  I am assuming something would need to be added to the onChange method inside the dateEditor function.

Comment: Moment js is mainly for formatting dates. You need to do the validation manually. This can probably be done with Tabulator’s validators or a custom validator function. The date picker needs to be done with the end date. I’ll make a fiddle with an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue using the datepicker inside of the cell, that I couldn't figure out.  An error is thrown about the instance data missing.

Here is an example using flatpickr instead of the jQuery datepicker.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/65t1dp23/49/

The two most important parts are including a validator, so that users cannot type in a date.  (I don't think they ever could, but if somehow they do it will prevent invalid dates.). The other is using the `maxDate` or equivalent parameter from the date picking library when you create the date picker instance.

Here is a custom validator to prevent any dates in the future. (It may not handle time differences properly in this setup.)

```
  function noFutureDate(cell, value){
    const cellValue = moment(new Date(value));
    const today = moment();
    if (cellValue.diff(today) > 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

You also have to create a custom editor.  Here is what you specifically need for the date picker instance.  You can get the rest from the fiddle, but the other parts aren't really related to a date picker specifically.

```
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.value = cell.getValue();
  onRendered(function(){
    flatpickr(input, {
      maxDate: moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    })
    input.focus();
  });
```

Comment: Once again, you have provided a quality solution.  The ```flatpickr``` plug-in works perfectly.  I'm glad I didn't waste a lot of time banging my head against the wall with the ```jQuery datepicker```.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn’t use jQuery UI on anything new as it appears to have been mostly abandoned. It definitely has a lot of convenient elements, but it doesn’t look like it will receive any official updates in the future.